# Regex to restrict certain numbers but allow all others

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex to allow only numbers except certain numbers

example: Restrict 101 - 109. All others are allowed

Tried

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^([0-9]+|[^10[1-9]]| [^0])$/);

regex.test(101)  // should give false

regex.test(109)  // should give false

regex.test(0)  // should give false
```

Any other value should give true

```
regex.test(100001) // should give true
```

This does not work

Comment: How is `0` false ? It's not between `101-109`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead based regex to disallow certain numbers while matching all numbers:

```
/^(?!(0|10[1-9])$)\d+$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jI3rP8/1)

`(?!(0|10[1-9])$)` is negative lookahead to disallow `0`, and all numbers from `101-109`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
!/^0|10[1-9]$/.test(101)
```

```js
function check_number(n){
    return !/^0|10[1-9]$/.test(n);
}

document.write('101 : '    + check_number(101)    + '<br>');
document.write('109 : '    + check_number(109)    + '<br>');
document.write('0 : '      + check_number(0)      + '<br>');
document.write('100001 : ' + check_number(100001) + '<br>');
```

Comment: I also want 1, 2, 234, 432 etc . All numbers should be allowed except 101 to 109

Answer (score 0):

Example: This restricts it to *238 - 971*
This is just showing that its not the restriction that is hard,
its generating a number range regex.
A good tool that does it for you is [here](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht0.jpg).

`^(?!0*(?:23[8-9]|2[4-9]\d|[3-8]\d{2}|9[0-6]\d|97[0-1])$)\d+$`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?!
      0*
      (?:
           23 [8-9] 
        |  2 [4-9] \d 
        |  [3-8] \d{2} 
        |  9 [0-6] \d 
        |  97 [0-1] 
      )
      $ 
 )
 \d+ 
 $
```